# Button действие при нажатии

Tags: php, button, action

Есть форма, в форме куча всяких `<textarea>` в конце формы стоит `<input type="submit">`. Добавил кнопку `<button>`, но почему-то при нажатии на эту кнопку вызывается submit... т.е. пытается отправить форму. пробовал `onclick`, `formaction`.

Comment: покажите код пожалуйста

Comment: onclick="return false;"

Comment: Для `button` атрибут `type` по-умолчанию стоит в `submit`. Вы изменили `type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам следовало бы почитать про атрибут Type. Вот пример обычной кнопки:

```
<button type="button">Обычная кнопка</button>
```

[Официальная документация](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button/type)